# Key error & Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, keyerror

I wrote a Python script (below) which load data from a text file (using `pandas`) and checks the values in the columns.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import ndarray
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from skimage import data
from skimage.feature import match_template

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = pd.read_csv('Fe_PSI_spt_refined.txt', sep=" ", header = None)
    data.columns = ["Angle_number", "Omega", "Intensity", "X", "Y", "Address", "ID"]#, "flag"]
    Number_of_projections = 181
    Number_of_lines_in_txt = 3493
    numrows = len(data)
    counter_array = []
    correlation_threshold_value = 0.7
    a = np.zeros(Number_of_lines_in_txt)
    output_file = ("output.txt")

    for i in range(2, (Number_of_projections + 1)): 
        filename_cutouts_combined = ("cutouts_combined_%03i.txt" % (i))
        filename_cutouts_combined_tag = ("cutouts_combined_tag_%03i.txt" % (i))
        image = np.loadtxt(filename_cutouts_combined)
        image_tagged = np.loadtxt(filename_cutouts_combined_tag)
        for j in range(0, Number_of_lines_in_txt - 1):
            print data.Angle_number[j], i
```

After one iteration of `j` I get the error below. Do you spot any error I should fix? Thanks

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Hyperbola_search.py", line 46, in <module>
    print data.Angle_number[j], i
  File "/Users/Alberto/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 491, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Users/Alberto/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1032, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
  File "index.pyx", line 97, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2661)
  File "index.pyx", line 105, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2476)
  File "index.pyx", line 149, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3215)
  File "hashtable.pyx", line 382, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6450)
  File "hashtable.pyx", line 388, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6394)
KeyError: 3491`
```

Answer (score 0):

You load files into `image` and `image_tagged`, while `a` remains unused.

I don't know what `data.Angle_number` and `numrows` are, but they appear to be from libraries, not related to your files.

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, I simplified my code a bit too much... I get data from reading a txt (see first two lines below `if __name__ == '__main__':`) in the updated version above.